# What is wrong with my auto complete?

Tags: swift, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

`Hello ☺️ I'm new to swift . I am working on Google map and Goole Place .
I have a search bar which when I click on the button and search the results should show in an auto complete position , But that's not work .
Here is my code :

```
func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 15.0)
    self.googleMapsView.camera = camera
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) //dismiss after select place
}

func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
    print("Erroe Auto Complte \(error)")
}
func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)//when cancel search

}

@IBAction func openSearchAddress(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let autoCompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autoCompleteController.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.present(autoCompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Declaration of variable**  
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var locationSelected = Location.startLocation
var locationStart = CLLocation()
var locationEnd = CLLocation()


**GMSMapViewDelegate Methods**

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        viewMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
        viewMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        if (gesture) {
            mapView.selectedMarker = nil
        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        viewMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        return false
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("COORDINATE \(coordinate)") // when you tapped coordinate
    }

    func didTapMyLocationButton(for mapView: GMSMapView) -> Bool {
        viewMap.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        viewMap.selectedMarker = nil
        return false
    }

 **StartLocation and DetinationLocation**
@IBAction func btnStartLocationPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let autoCompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autoCompleteController.delegate = self
        // selected location
        locationSelected = .startLocation
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.present(autoCompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func btnDetinationLocation(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let autoCompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autoCompleteController.delegate = self
        // selected location
        locationSelected = .destinationLocation
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.present(autoCompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

**This is Extension for GMSAutocompleteViewController put after ViewController class** 


extension ViewController: GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate {

    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func viewController(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController, didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {

        // Change map location
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 16.0
        )
        // set coordinate to text
        if locationSelected == .startLocation {
            btnStart.setTitle("\(place.coordinate.latitude), \(place.coordinate.longitude)", for: .normal) 
            locationStart = CLLocation(latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
        } else {
            btndesti.setTitle("\(place.coordinate.latitude), \(place.coordinate.longitude)", for: .normal)
            locationEnd = CLLocation(latitude: place.coordinate.latitude, longitude: place.coordinate.longitude)
        }
        self.viewMap.camera = camera
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func wasCancelled(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }

    func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(_ viewController: GMSAutocompleteViewController) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

}
```

> using locationStart and locationEnd you can draw polyline